# Can't run class with mysql connector from command line

Tags: java, mysql, macos

I'm trying to run a compiled java class file that uses a MySQL connector `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`, but the execution keeps failing.  It works fine when running in and IDE such as eclipse.

`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode/` contains the following files:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
Version.class
Version.java
```

After navigating to `~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode/` in Terminal, I can;t figure out how to get it to run properly.

Here are my attempts and their results.

Attempt #1
`java -cp /java -cp /mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar Version`

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Version`
```

Attempt #2
`java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar Version`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Version (wrong name: zetcode/Version)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:
```

Attempt #3
`java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar Version`

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
            (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
-bash: mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar: command not found
```

Attempt #4
I moved `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin` out of the zetcode folder and put it one level up in the lib folder.  Then I re-navigated so that I am now in `~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/` and ran:
`java -cp .:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar zetcode/Version`

```
May 02, 2014 10:54:31 PM zetcode.Version main
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at zetcode.Version.main(Version.java:24)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jar in your classpath.  Pointing your classpath at a directory will make the the ClassLoader look in that directory for classes but it won't see those jars and look in side those.  Each element in the classpath is a root under which the classloader will scan for classes and resources.  Nested classpath roots are not supported by the JRE ClassLoaders.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the jar is included in the classpath.  I've edited the original post to include three attempts and their results.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks

Comment: I added a 4th attempt and it's results

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
set classpath="mysql jar location";.;
javac fileName.java
```

Comment: Surrender Kannan huh?  I didn't ask how to compile.  The .class file has already been created.